# Cartesian Products of Union is equal to union of cartesian products

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking at the proof of "Cavalieris Principle" in my textbook.
We have two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu),(Y,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{v})$. Since they are $\sigma$-finite we can choose sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ from $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ respectively such that
$$
\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n =X, \quad \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n =Y, \quad \mu(A_n),\mathcal{v}(B_n)<\infty $$
If we define $H_n = A_n \times B_n$ for all n, will we then have that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} H_n =X \times Y$ no matter what, or do we have to assume anything about the sequences? E.g. do $(A_n),(B_n)$ have to be increasing sequences, which I know we can choose since the measure spaces are $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: If you define $H_n=A_n \times B_n$, you need to require that the $\{A_n\}_n$ and $\{B_n\}_n$ are increasing sequences of sets.  However, you can define $H_{n,m}=A_n \times B_m$.  Then $\{H_{n,m}\}_{n,m}$ is a countable family of sets and $X \times Y = \bigcup_{n,m} H_{n,m}$. In this way, no additional assumption is needed about  $\{A_n\}_n$ and $\{B_n\}_n$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make assumptions about the sequences of the sets.

Let's just look at these: $A_1 = B_2 = [0, 1]$ and all other elements of the sequences are empty sets.

Then all $H_n = \emptyset$ (and so is their union) but we have $X \times Y = [0, 1]^2$.